# No se insertan registros en base de datos mysql

Tags: mysql, python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Tengo un problema con al insertar registros en base de datos MySQL con python, usando el código que se muestra más adelante intento insertar los valores qe muestro y no me aparecen en la DB. Hice una consulta y si se hace correctamente, revisé los parámetros y también no tienen ningún error, tengo un arduino que continuamente inserta en esa base de datos por lo que dudo que el problema sea de la DB. Todo lo hago en Raspbian usando una Raspberry Pi 3

El código a continuación

```
import mysql.connector

dato = {
 'user':'user',
 'password':'password',
 'database':'database',
 'host':'www.midireccion.com'
 } 

con = mysql.connector.connect(** dato)
cursor = con.cursor()
valores = "INSERT INTO DispData (Dis,H,S) VALUES 
('85439313130351D032D0','62','0')"

try:
    con.cursor(valores)
    con.commit()
    print("Valores ingresados correctamente")
except:
    print("Error")

con.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías tu except por esto?

```
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
   print("Hubo un error: {}".format(err))
```

De esta forma podríamos saber mas al respecto

```
// sacado de las documentaciones de MySQL-Python:
-> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-errors-error.html
```

Comment: Se me pasó un detalle, me aparece "Valores ingresados correctamente" al intentar ingresar registro pero en la DB no aparece nada